# Can't use private property in extensions in another file

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I can't use private property in extension. My extension is in another file.

How can I use private property in extension?

Comment: Did you tried to use `fileprivate` instead of `private` ?

Comment: @thedjnivek `My extension is in another file.`

Comment: Are you sure that worked in Swift 2?? "private" in Swift 2 restricts access to the *same source file*.

Comment: @MartinR I'm not sure because I just separate file for main class and extension after I upgraded to swift 3

Comment: So your problem is unrelated to Swift 2 vs Swift 3 and *"After I have upgraded to swift 3.0. I can't use private property in extension"* is misleading.

Comment: I would say it doesn't make any to have private func/property in an extension. as they have to be accesable from an outside class

Comment: @DanielPoulsen I'd disagree with that assessment of whether or not it makes sense to have private members in extensions.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

**Update**
Starting with Swift 4, extensions can access the private properties of a type declared in the same file. See [Access Levels](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AccessControl.html).

If a property is declared `private`, its access is restricted to the enclosing declaration, and to extensions of that declaration that are in the same file.

If the property is declared `fileprivate`, it can only be used within the file it is declared (and by *anything* in that file).

If the property is declared `internal` (the default), it can only be used within the module it is declared (and by *anything* in that file).

If the property is declared `public` or `open`, it can be used by anything within the module as well as outside of the module by files that import the module it is declared in.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, This's really clear for me. but I just need to clean up my code. I just want to make it clearer. so that why I separate extension out of main file. and yes you understand exactly. I don't want any class touch on this property. which one do you prefer between make it to be an internal property (I can separate file) and make it fileprivate (keep them back in to main file)

Comment: Different situations call for different use cases.

Comment: My extension using for setting styles in an object. I decided to use fileprivate for now. I'll keep them back to main file.

Answer (score 7):

While @nhgrif is correct about how painful is that `protected` is missing in Swift, There is a way around.

Wrap your object with `protocol`, and declare only about the methods and properties that you wish to expose.

For Example

**MyUtiltyClass.swift**

```
protocol IMyUtiltyClass {
    func doSomething()
}

class MyUtiltyClass : IMyUtiltyClass {

    static let shared : IMyUtiltyClass = MyUtiltyClass()

    /*private*/
    func doSomethingPrivately() {

    }
}
```

**MyUtiltyClass+DoSomething.swift**

```
extension MyUtiltyClass {
    func doSomething() {
        self.doSomethingPrivately()
        print("doing something")
    }
}
```

And then you treat the object as the interface type and not the class/struct type directly.

**MyViewController.swift**

```
class MyViewController : UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        MyUtiltyClass.shared.doSomething()
        /*
         //⚠️ compiler error
         MyUtiltyClass.shared.doSomethingPrivately()
         */
    }
}
```

Happy Coding ‍

Comment: I find this answer very useful. Specially now that I'm creating an App Clip and quite often I have a shared file (target both app and clip) with a class and an extension of the class for the main app only, for example. Thanks!

Comment: This trick would not work if you have variables. In this example you can see the compiler gives an error when trying to set the property



```protocol Protocol {
    var example: Bool { get set }
}
class Test: Protocol {
    var example: Bool = true
    static let shared: Protocol = Test()
    
    private init() { }
}

Test.shared.example
Test.shared.example = false // Throws error "Cannot assign to property: 'shared' is a 'let' constant"
```

Comment: @Elena. If you intend to use the protocol for reference variables. Then mention it in the protocol definition, as follow
`protocol Protocol: AnyObject {` or `protocol Protocol: class {`

Comment: I just found "Jump to Definition" will go to protocol after refactored my class (1000+ lines). Then, I reverted all the changes.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a good practice to write a private variable in extensions (even if we can). It will introduce unexpected bugs.

If you want to access the variable, you can use private(set) for that variable to make it read only for outside world.

Ex.

```
private(set) var myPrivateVariable:Int
```

Comment: Not sure way this answer was unvoted, it solves the issue.

Comment: It did not, if the extension is in another file you only have read access, not write access.

Comment: Ya this is for accessing only, the point is, if we are able to have write access then over the time as code grows it will introduce bugs as any one can write it and 'private' wont make any sense.

Comment: This is not about accessing property from multiple classes (where you indeed should use `private(set)`. This is about asymmetry where extension defined in the same class has access to private vars and the extension in different file cannot. This answer has nothing to do with original question.