# Why private is unaccessible to the extension?

Tags: swift, xcode, access-control, swift4

Here is my *ViewController.swift* file:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    private var myInt = 10
}

extension ViewController {
    func printMyInt() {
        print(myInt)
    }
}
```

Although as mentioned in the [Swift documentation - Access Levels section](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH41-ID5):

> Private access restricts the use of an entity to the enclosing
>   declaration, **and to extensions of that declaration that are in the**
>   **same file**. Use private access to hide the implementation details of a
>   specific piece of functionality when those details are used only
>   within a single declaration.

Since Swift 4 has been released, I assume that I am able to implement such a thing (it is also mentioned in: [What's New in Swift - WWDC 2017](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/402/) session), however, the complier shows me:

[image]

> 'myInt' is inaccessible due to 'private' protection level

Is it incompatible with what mentioned in the documentation?

As a simple quick solution, I could declare it as:

```
fileprivate var myInt = 10
```

but I wonder why is it behaves like this, am I misunderstand what mentioned in the documentation? or is it a "Xcode" bug (used 9.0.1 version)?

***Remark***: The project has been created in the older Xcode 8 and then *migrated* to Xcode 9.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In **Swift 4**, `private` members *are* accessible to extensions of that declaration that are in the same file, see [SE-0169 – Improve Interaction Between private Declarations and Extensions](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0169-improve-interaction-between-private-declarations-and-extensions.md).

If the project has been created in Xcode 8 (with Swift 3) then
Xcode 9 will open it in "Swift 3 mode" and set the "Swift Language Version" to "Swift 3.2". Therefore the stricter Swift 3 restrictions hold.

To make the private extension visible to extension in the same file,
set the Swift language version to 4 in the build settings. (Of course
that might make more changes in your code necessary.)

Even better, use "Edit -> Convert -> To Current Swift Syntax ..."

Comment: Note the "extensions **that are in the same file**" qualifier - the private members are [inaccessible to an extension in a separate file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39747929/cant-use-private-property-in-extensions-in-another-file).